# showing parallel operations using flow chart

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to represent an algorithm with a flow chart, and I am trying to use standard notations as much as possible.

I want represent the following expression with flowchart:

```
for i=1:N
   if ai>3 set m(i) = x(i)
   else set mi = y(i)
end
```

However, I want to show that the operations in the `for` loop take place in parallel, i.e. all `m(i)` are computed synchronously. Is it possible to express this expression with flow chart?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't relate to writing code, but creating diagrams.

Comment: I think it's up to you to make something up. My impression is that flow charts diminished in use before parallelism emerged into widespread use.

Comment: @user3386109 I agree; a had submitted a paper to some journal one of the reviewers asked for flowchart! as my method is parallel i cant figure it up how to represent this